# Showing that $a_n := H_n - \ln(n)$ is decreasing

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

I'm trying to prove that $a_n := H_n - \ln(n)$ is decreasing, where $H_n$ is the Harmonic Series $H_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}$.

I tried going about it with Integrals and I was quite easily able to show the following

$$\int_1^{n+1} \frac{1}{x} \, dx \leq H_n \leq \int_1^{n} \frac{1}{x} \, dx + 1$$

$$\ln(n+1) \leq H_n \leq \ln(n) + 1$$

$$\ln(1 + \frac{1}{n}) \leq a_n \leq 1$$

This shows that $a_n \in [0, 1]$, but I can't quite show that its then also necessarily decreasing. I feel like I'm just missing some obvious bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider $ x_n =1+ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} +  \cdots + \frac{1}{n} -\ln n = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i} -\ln n $.

Then we have $x_{n+1}-x_n= \frac{1}{n+1}-\ln \left(1+\frac{1}{n} \right) < 0 $.

**Addition.**

Accordingly to request in comment let's consider $ y_n=\left(1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^{n+1} $. From one hand $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}y_n =\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^{n+1} = e $. From another hand from inequality:
$$\frac{y_n}{y_{n-1}} = \frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^{n+1}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n-1} \right)^{n}} = \frac{1}{\left( 1+\frac{1}{n^2-1}\right)^n }\cdot\frac{n+1}{n}<\frac{1}{ 1+\frac{n}{n^2-1} }\cdot\frac{n+1}{n}<1$$
we see, that $y_n $ is decreasing, so, is more, then it's limit i.e. holds $e < \left(1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^{n+1} =y_n $. Last is equivalent $ \frac{1}{n+1}-\ln \left(1+\frac{1}{n} \right) < 0 $.

Comment: But wouldn't I then need to show that $\frac{1}{n+1} \lt ln(1 + \frac{1}{n})$ ?

Comment: Of course. I'll wrote addition.

Comment: Sure. For $x\in(1,1+1/n)$ $$\frac{n}{n+1}<\frac1x.$$ Now integrate both sides from $x=1$ to $x=1+1/n.$ @roblox99

Comment: @roblox99. Wrote as promised.  Thomas Andrews  also suggested nice idea.

Comment: @zkutch. Thank you for your addition. It just flew right past me to rewrite $\frac{1}{n+1} \lt ln(1 + frac{1}{n})$ as $1 \lt ln((1 + \frac{1}{n})^{n+1})$