# Can you explain me how this Big O notation is used?

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

So I was reading a book in analytic number theory and there was this claim
$$\sum_{a\leq x} 1/a =\log x+O(1)$$
and since we kinda skipped these big $O$ notation problems at early uni days I got wondering how I can be sure in something like this?

I mean I can see how $\sum_{a\leq x} 1/a \leq \log x$ holds but how can I be sure that the rest is $O(1)$?

Also if I take $\sum_{a\leq x} O(1)$, $O(1)$ I can get out of the sum and the sum is something that is less than $x$ so $O(x)$ so that gives me $O(1)O(x)$ which is $O(x)$, am I correct?

Comment: $$
\log n = \int_1^n {\frac{{dx}}{x}}  < \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{k}}  < 1 + \int_1^n {\frac{{dx}}{x}}  = 1 + \log n
$$

Comment: Can you explain first how the first inequality holds and how this answers my question?

Comment: Note that $$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{k}}  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\int_k^{k + 1} {\frac{{dx}}{k}} }  \ge \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\int_k^{k + 1} {\frac{{dx}}{x}} }  = \int_1^{n + 1} {\frac{{dx}}{x}}  = \log (n + 1) > \log n.
$$ The inequalities show that $\sum\nolimits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{k}}  - \log n$ is bounded, i.e., $$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{k}}  = \log n + \mathcal{O}(1).
$$

Comment: Does this help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4139408/showing-that-a-n-h-n-lnn-is-decreasing/4139413#4139413?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the comments to this question and add one bit of extra info, the notation
$$
f(x) = O(g(x))
$$
is defined to mean that $\left| f(x)\right| \leq C g(x)$, where $C$ is a constant independent of $x$. For your specific question, one needs to show that for some suitable constant $C$, we have
$$
\left| \sum_{a \leq x} \frac{1}{a} - \log x\right| \leq C.
$$
From the comments provided by Gary, we have precisely this inequality with $C = 1$. In fact, one can use [partial summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula) to deduce that
$$
\sum_{a \leq x} \frac{1}{a} = \log x + \gamma + O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right),
$$
where $\gamma$ denotes the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant). In general, when dealing with the sums
$$
\sum_{a\leq x} f(a)
$$
where $f$ is differentiable (or, say, continuously differentiable $k$ times), you should expect the sum above to be comparable to the integral
$$
\int_{1}^{x} f(t) dt.
$$
Indeed, this is precisely the content of the [Euler-Maclaurin summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula).

By a more careful analysis, one can obtain an asymptotic expansion of the sum above with an arbitrarily small error term. For instance, if $\psi(x) = \left\{ x\right\} - \frac{1}{2}$, where $\left\{ x\right\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$, then
$$
\sum_{a \leq x} \frac{1}{a} = \log x + \gamma  - \frac{\psi(x)}{x} + O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right).
$$