# Showing the existence of the Euler-Mascheroni constant

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function, constants, digamma-function

I want to show that there exists a constant $\gamma$ such that:

$$- \frac{\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)} = \gamma + \frac{1}{z} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{z+n}-\frac{1}{n} \right)$$

where $\Gamma$ is the Gamma function. This constant is known as the Euler (-Mascheroni) constant, and I would like to prove its existence without directly computing it. Is that possible? We know a few basic properties about the Gamma function, for example:

$$\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z) = \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}$$

I got a tip: Find a 1-periodic function and use the functional equation of $\Gamma$ and $\sin$ to find a bound for the growth. All the proofs that I saw where very computation heavy, and I got told that we can prove the existence of such a $\gamma$ without much computation. Can someone give me some advice, what I could try here?

Comment: Proving that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + \frac12 + \dots + \frac1n - \ln n)$ exists seems easier.

Comment: Note that  $\frac{\Gamma'(1)}{\Gamma(1)}=\int_0^\infty \log(t) e^{-t}$, which we will call $-\gamma\,$ (it does exist).  That should do it.

Comment: [SEE THIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Series_formula).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4139408/showing-that-a-n-h-n-lnn-is-decreasing/4139413#4139413

Comment: You can use the Weierstrass product for $\Gamma$ (in its general form, without even knowning that the constant in the exponential is $-\gamma$).

Comment: I think the 1-periodic function that is mentioned is $\varphi(z) = -\frac{\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)} - \frac{1}{z} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{z+n} - \frac{1}{n}\right)$. This function is 1-periodic and should be constant, how do i show that it's constant?

Comment: A constant function is not $1$-periodic (in the primitive sense). Your right that the $\varphi(z)$ you have written is constant, though (because that is what you are asked to prove).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to prove the Euler–Mascheroni constant exists. Here is one of the typical proofs that works directly from its definition.

We begin with by defining
$$
\gamma:=\lim_{n\to\infty}\gamma_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}(H_n-\log n),
\tag{1}
$$
with $H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}$ being the harmonic numbers. It follows from the integral representation of the natural logarithm
$$
\begin{align}
\gamma_n
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}-\int_1^n\frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm dx\\
&=\frac{1}{n}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}-\int_1^n\frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm dx\\
&=\frac{1}{n}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\int_k^{k+1}\frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm dx\\
&=\frac{1}{n}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{k}-\int_k^{k+1}\frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm dx\right).
\end{align}
$$
Now make the observation that for some constant $c$
$$
\int_k^{k+1}c\,\mathrm dx=cx\big|_{x=k}^{k+1}=c;
$$
hence,
$$
\gamma_n
=\frac{1}{n}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\int_k^{k+1}\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{x}\right)\,\mathrm dx.
$$
The integrand $\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{x}$ is nonnegative for each $k$ showing that $\gamma_n\geq0$ and therefore if $\gamma$ exists, it must be nonnegative. To establish $\gamma$ exists we just need to prove that $\lim_{n,\to\infty}\gamma_n$ converges. We do this by first writing
$$
\begin{align}
\int_k^{k+1}\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{x}\right)\,\mathrm dx
&\leq \int_k^{k+1}\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)\,\mathrm dx\\
&=\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}\\
&=\frac{1}{k(k+1)}\\
&\leq\frac{1}{k^2}.
\end{align}
$$
So
$$
0\leq\gamma\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}<\infty,
$$
which completes the proof.